# Why is this output reached?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, es6-promise

Can anyone tell me why this code outputs the following? I am completely lost on async functions and close to just giving up.

The first await does what I expect and waits 1 second before executing. However, somehow 301 is outputted before the `then` before it is executed which seems to completely defy the literal definition of `then`. Done is outputted then somehow it goes back and executes the second then statement.

```js
async function test() {

  const promise1 = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('foo');
      console.log('First await executed')
    }, 1000)
  }).then(() => {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('foo');
        console.log("This was executed")
      }, 1000)
    })
  }).then(() => Promise.resolve(301));

  console.log(promise1)

  await setTimeout(() => console.log(1000), 1000)

  console.log("Done");
}

test()
```

Comment: You are not returning the Promise within the first `.then()`, so it is completely unrelated to the other Promise chain.

Comment: Doesn't resolve pass its value?

Comment: Not if you don't do anything with the Promise you are constructing. The `then()` callback will be executed in order, but it only constructs a Promise and then continues. If you want it to wait for the promise before continuing, you'll need to either `await` it, or `return` it.